Cannot see schemas of database other than the default database in eclipse IDE for postgreSQL database when to generate entities from tables
I want to generate entities for tables that are present in my postgreSQL database schema, I've done the same for mySQL database before, the problem I'm facing is that after establishing the connection successfully I am unable to see any schemas that are present in that database. But when I make the connection for the default database (postgres) all the schemas show up correctly. The following are the screenshots for the same problem the first one is for the default database and ideally for my other database (test) the schemas should show up in the same way. And also in the data source explorer tab where the connections are showed I can see all the schemas and tables correctly even for the non-default database (test). The data source explorer tab is in the bottom left side of the screenshots.
screenshot for default db connection (postgres) :

As you can see the schemas are listed properly and when I select anyone of them I am able to see and select tables that are present in those schemas also in the bottom left you can see for this connection all the schemas are listed in the data source explorer.
Screenshot for connection to database created by me (test):

In this connection which is for database created by me, I am unable to see and select any schemas but in the data source explorer (bottom left) I can see all the schemas and also the table. Any help of any kind of direction would be really helpful.

I am not seeing schemas in the connection in either screenshot. Betting it is due message Note: you must an active connection to select schema.

@AdrianKlaver the connection is successful, and in bottom left I can see all the schemas , I will update the screenshots they are incorrect, but the description is correct.
